# Oracle: apply multiple updates in single statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a simple update of one table with data from another table.

```
update t1
   set (a,b) = (select a,b from t2 where id=17)
 where id=17;
```

How can i apply a similar update to multiple id's in one statement?  In my brain I'm thinking iteratively of something like this:

```
for X in (select id from t2 where ...):
    update t1
       set (a,b) = (select a,b from t2 where id=X)
     where id=X;
```

Generic SQL preferred, but Oracle-specific solutions welcomed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
update t1
   set (a, b) = (select a,b from t2 where t2.id=t1.id)
 where t1.id in (select id from t2 where ...);
```